# Reading char* from specific index C

Tags: c, string, char, memcpy

I have a `char *message;` which contains some content.
I wish to read this message from a specific index (for example 20) and until end of the `char*`. Is there any clever way to do this? I have been looking at `memcpy()` and the possibility to copy a "sub-string" from `message` into a new `char *tmp;`, but I can't seem to figure out how to start at that specific index (for example 20) and copy until end of `message` -- rather than starting at the beginning of `message`.

Any help appreciated. Cheers!

Comment: `char *tmp = message + 20;`

Comment: &message[20] would work as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may try like this:

```
char *tmp= message + 20;
```

Comment: @matkapluku This however still points to the same memory as the original string if you want to modify it without modifying the original string you can do this with strcpy(dest, message+20);

Answer (score 0):

this is an example to test your need :

```
main()
{

   char *buff = "hello_word_test";
   char *tmp;

   printf("%s \n",buff);
   printf("%s \n",buff+5);


}
```

result :

```
    hello_word_test 
   _word_test
```

5 is an index , you can change it as well as you need